# Почему JS уходит в бесконечный цикл на втором проходе

Tags: javascript, циклы

Кусок кода обрабатывает входную строку, взятую из базы, если длина строки больше 1000 знаков, она разбивается на страницы и заливается в блок кусками с добавлением переключателей страниц
При первом проходе, то есть сразу после загрузки страницы(и первого обращения к базе) всё проходит как надо.
Но если пользователь инициирует AJAX-обращение на замену текста(не страницы, а всего текста для блока), то браузер зацикливается на третьей-шестой строке

```
    if(ii>item.page_text.length){
            ii=item.page_text.length;
            ii--;
    }
```

Вопрос: почему?

**Важное уточнение** Код не просто делит строку на фрагменты по 1000 знаков. Он ищет ближайший конец предложения обозначенный точкой в сторону уменьшения количества знаков.

Вот сам ответственный кусок кода

```
    var i=0;
    var ii=0;
    pageText=new Array();
    for( ii=1000;i<item.page_text.length-1;ii=i+1000) {
        if(ii<item.page_text.length){
            while(ii>i){
                if (item.page_text[ii]!="."){
                    ii--;
                }
                else
                {
                    ii++;
                    pageText.push("<p>"+item.page_text.slice(i,ii)+"</p>");
                    i=ii;
                    $(".book-text-choose-first").before("<span class=\"book-text-page-num\" id=\"page#"+pageText.length+"\">"+pageText.length+"</span>");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            ii=item.page_text.length-1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: какое значение у `i` в самом начале приведённого фрагмента?

Comment: а, прошу прощения, потерял строку     `var i=0`

Comment: Посмотрите выполнение этого кода пошагово в дебаггере. В Chrome developer tools или FireBug.

Comment: Посмотрел. Именно так я понял, на каких строках зависает браузер. Но всё ещё не понимаю, почему.

Comment: Да, нашёл. У меня ошибка в логике. условный оператор, проверяющий выход за пределы допустимого значения направлял не на дальнейшее выполнение кода, а на завершение итерации цикла for, который при начале новой итерации прибавлял 1000 к нужному значению, что снова направляло по if на уменьшение значения и так по кругу. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

В коде с множеством циклов и счетчиков, очень тяжело найти ошибку, вот такой код, я думаю вам подойдет лучше

```js
/*в переменной page должен быть текст статьи, 
переменная content должна указывать на тег в котором должна быть статья,
а тег navBar на тег в котором должна быть навигация,
я использовал интервал 10, в вашем случае поменяйте его на 1000, 
после чего можете применять этот код*/
var page="aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbccccccccccddddddddddeeeeeeeeee";
  var content=document.getElementById("content");
  var navBar=document.getElementById("navbar");
  var listPages=[];
  content.textContent=page.substring(0,10);
  for(var i=1;page.length>=10;i++){
   listPages[i]=page.substring(0,10);
   page=page.substring(10,page.length);
   var navIndex=document.createElement("a");
   navIndex.href="";
   navIndex.textContent=""+i;
   navIndex.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var textNavIndex=e.currentTarget.textContent;
    content.textContent=listPages[parseInt(textNavIndex)];
   },false);
   navBar.appendChild(navIndex);
  }
```

```html
 <div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="navbar"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Благодарю за решение, но я хотел бы понять именно _что я делал не так_, в чём я ошибся, чтоб в дальнейшем так не делать. Если не очень сложно, подскажите, как не это быстрее понять, не заменяя бездумно свой код на ваш.

Comment: не чем не могу помочь, у меня от циклов голова кружится)

Comment: Ладно, всё равно, спасибо=) Кстати, в уведомлениях сайта висит неоткрываемая первая редакция ответа, думаю, ваша. В сочетании с нынешним причёсанным вариантом он выглядит абсолютно бесподобно=)